# How to apply GString interpolation in a js file in Grails

Tags: javascript, grails, gstring

My GSP file (in Grails 3.1.10):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <asset:javascript src="jquery-2.2.0.min.js"/>
    <asset:javascript src="myfile.js"/>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="greeting"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

myfile.js:

```
greeting = "${resp}"; // resp is passed from controller
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#greeting').val(greeting);
});
```

Well, I believe in that every grails developer knows if I move myfile.js into my GSP file, it will work.

However, I hope to know how to let the standalone js file can handle the inline variable of GString correctly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the approach I followed when ran into same problem like yours.

Pass your GString variable to external JS by following way.

Add the below function in your external JS

```
function view_handler_function(greetingValue){

    //assign the value to your element
    $('#greeting').val(greetingValue);

    .....
    //Your other handling code
}
```

Call your function from your view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <asset:javascript src="jquery-2.2.0.min.js"/>
    <asset:javascript src="myfile.js"/>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="greeting"></span>

    <script>
        var greeting = "${resp}"; // resp is passed from controller
        $(document).ready(function(){

            //call to your external function 
            view_handler_function(greeting);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** This may or may not be the exact answer you are looking for but just one way around I follow.

Comment: well, basically, your way is the same as that of norganos (above). What if I have many variables ? is this still your suggested way ?

Comment: Yes.  You can create map of your variables(if more than 5) and then send it to external JS function.

Answer (score 1):

this is out of the box simply not possible, and it's not a good idea either (although of course you could use a controller action as javascript src and in that action read in the js file and run it's content through a e.g. simpleTemplateEngine)

having js files be interpreted like gstrings/other templates would mean that any caching (bundle files via asset pipeline, cdn distribution and browser caching) had to be disabled.

however, you can simply serve the js files statically and e.g. provide your dynamic input as global variables in inline javascript (e.g. from your layout):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="greeting"></span>
    <g:javascript>
      var greeting = "${resp}";
    </g:javascript>
    <asset:javascript src="jquery-2.2.0.min.js"/>
    <asset:javascript src="myfile.js"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: #norganos, what if I have many variables (ex: 20~30) ? Is this still your suggested way ?

Comment: yes (probably until someone comes up with a better idea), I use this kind of pattern in two projects, each having around 15-20 vars that have to be set dynamically, wrapped in a global object. you could of course avoid the globals by using init functions.